# In generalized additive models, how does B-spline handle testing data that are out of range

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, splines

In GAM, a general approach is to use B-spline basis expansion to approximate the true nonparametric function. Usually the edge knots are chosen as the minimum and maximum of the training data (for continuous predictors). However, it is very possible that a predictor in the testing data fall outside of the range between the training minimum and maximum. The B-spline basis expansion on the training set was not defined on such values. What are the possible ways to handle these points?

(For example, how does the bs() function in R handle these points?)

Comment: Beyond the general dangers of extrapolation, is there some reason why you can't use restricted cubic splines, which enforce linear extrapolation beyond the original data limits?

Comment: @EdM Thanks for replying. In practice we can definitely use restricted cubic splines, but for this problem I have to use B-spline. That's why I'm trying to understand how functions like bs()/splev handle these points.

Comment: Hi. I have exactly the same problem. I searched and found your question. Could you find any solution for this problem? How did you predict a new x using obtained B spline coefficients?